# Group list by a given element and calculate the mean

Tags: python, list

If have the following list:

```
l = [(('01001', '01003'), 4.15),
 (('01001', '01005'), 2.83),
 (('01001', '01007'), 3.32),
 (('01002', '01009'), 6.83),
 (('01002', '01011'), 2.53),
 (('01003', '01013'), 20.50),
 (('01003', '01013'), 20.50)]
```

I would like to calculate the mean value for the first element of this list ('01001', '01002', and '01003').

My appraoch so far was to transform the list into a dataframe and split the first bracket into two columns and than calculated the mean. Is there a more pythonic way?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this work ? `sum([int(t[0][0]) for t in l])/len(l)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas seems quite overkill for this. Since those values to be *grouped* seem to be consecutive (otherwise use a dictionary instead), you could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and take the mean of those floats:

```
from itertools import groupby
from statistics import mean

[mean(v for *_, v in v) for k,v in groupby(l, lambda x: x[0][0])]
# [3.4333333333333336, 4.68, 20.5]
```

Or if you prefer a dictionary:

```
{k:mean(v for *_, v in v) for k,v in groupby(l, lambda x: x[0][0])}
# {'01001': 3.4333333333333336, '01002': 4.68, '01003': 20.5}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
from statistics import mean
l = [(('01001', '01003'), 4.15),
 (('01001', '01005'), 2.83),
 (('01001', '01007'), 3.32),
 (('01002', '01009'), 6.83),
 (('01002', '01011'), 2.53),
 (('01003', '01013'), 20.50),
 (('01003', '01013'), 20.50)]
 
print(mean(int(x[0][0]) for x in l))
```

output

```
1001.8571428571429
```